# angular 4 select box and disable button

Tags: angular, select, button, dropdown

I have select box and I want to disable button when select first option.

```
<select>
  <option value="0">first option</option>
  <option value="1">second option</option>
  <option value="3">third option</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="primary">Submit</button>
```

Comment: no duplicate, I think my question is defferent

Comment: @Ruwa. Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to code anything in .ts for this.

Try this

```
 <select #selectoption>
      <option value="0">first option</option>
      <option value="1">second option</option>
      <option value="3">third option</option>
  </select>

<button type="submit" class="primary" [disabled]="selectoption.value =='0'">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will disable submit button on selecting  first option

In your **Html** file

```
<select [(ngModel)]="dropdownValue" (ngModelChange)="disableButton($event)">
  <option value="first">first option</option>
  <option value="second">second option</option>
  <option value="third">third option</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="primary" [disabled]=disableButtonMode>Submit</button>
```

**TS** file

```
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 6';
  dropdownValue:string;
  disableButtonMode:boolean=false;
  disableButton(){
    console.log(this.dropdownValue);
    if(this.dropdownValue=='first'){
  this.disableButtonMode=true;
    }
    else{
        this.disableButtonMode=false;
    }
  }
}
```

For reference use the following [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwechd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to test the code

Answer (score 0):

In your typescript initialize `Select` Model like

```
Select: any = '-1';
```

Now you should do in your html like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="Select">
  <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
  <option value="0">first option</option>
  <option value="1">second option</option>
  <option value="3">third option</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" class="primary" [disabled]="Select==0">Submit</button>
```

Here is working demo: [First Option Disabled](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ra4gm2)

Hope this will work for you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok then,

Submit

Than in the trigger:

```
<select (change)="checkValidation($event.target.value)">
  <option value="0">first option</option>
  <option value="1">second option</option>
  <option value="3">third option</option>
</select>
```

The function:

```
 isValid: boolean = false;

 checkValidation(value:any):void{
  console.log(value);
   if(value == 0){
     this.isValid=false;
   }
   else{
     this.isValid=true;
   }
 }
```

You can find a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/60qz1nw3/)

Anyway this is a didactic example without using 2 way binding maybe not the optimal solution